# Nested table increasing the width of the outer table

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I have a nested table as:

```
<table border="0" width="750" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr align="center">
     <td width="530">
         <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="530">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                   <tr>
                            <td width="14"></td>
                            <td width="177">
                                <p style="color:#333333; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-align: left; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">Expand Your Reach</p>
                                <ul style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; list-style-image:url(http://demo.frostmiller.com/sss104/images/bullet.jpg);text-align:left; margin-left: 25px; padding:0; list-style-position:outside;">
                                    <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
                                    <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
                                    <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                            </td>
                            <td width="29"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <hr width="220" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="14"></td>
                            <td width="177" align="left">
                                <p style="color:#333333; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-align: left;">Contact Info</p>
                                <p style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 2cm;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer  .</p>
                            </td>
                            <td width="29"></td>
                        </tr>
                </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
     <td width="220">
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am creating an html email, hence no other option but to nest tables.

Here as soon as I include the inner table of width 530 inside the cell of width 530, the border of the outer table gets misaligned and widens. How can I stop this?

Comment: Not nesting tables would be a good start. I've never seen a situation where nested tables correctly describe a data structure.

Comment: Agree with @David.  How do you want the data presented?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem with the code you have provided.  I also don't see any images except for the list marker.  However if you are including other images ensure that they are not wider than the column you are trying to place them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your HTML is invalid, the tables are wrongly nested (there's extra `tr` and `td` elements in there)
2. The maths don't add up so it's hard to figure what you're doing, the nested table is `14+177+29 = 220` but you have it inside the `530` cell
3. If you fix the nesting and change

   ```
   <td width="530">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="530">
   ```

   to:

   ```
   <td width="530">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
   ```

   it should fix any alignment problems that are still left

Answer (score 0):

Add `colspan="4"` to the outer `<td>` that houses the nested `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following css to the outer table:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

It doesn't allow the outer table to be wider than the set value of width. Example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
.outer-table, .outer-table td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.outer-table {
  width: 300px;
  /* Don't allow outer table to have width bigger than the set value (300px) */
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.inner-table {
  /* The width is bigger than the width of the outer table */
  width: 500px;
}
.inner-table, .inner-table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.inner-table-parent {
  /* Allow to scroll nested table */
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<table class="outer-table">
  <tr>
    <td>First column of outer table</td>
    <td class="inner-table-parent">
      <div>Second column of outer table with a nested table having width bigger that the outer</div>
      <table class="inner-table">
        <tr>
          <td>First column of inner table</td>
          <td>Second column of inner table</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello san4o, welcome to SO! The code snippets are great but in general I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you please elaborate more on the desired outcome?